# SICP car/cdr practice question problem

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

I'm trying out this "online tutor" for SICP here: http://icampustutor.csail.mit.edu/6.001-public/tutor.cgi?op=registration-page

I'm looking at the following question:

> Assume that we have already evaluated
>   the form

```
(define thing (cons (cons (cons 1 nil) nil)
                    (cons (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))
                          (cons 2
                               (cons 3 nil))))) Write expressions
```

> using only car, cdr, and thing whose
>   values are the list structures given
>   below.
>
> (1)
>   1
>   (2 3)
>   (3)

I'm having issues with the last one. I figured out a way using back-quote and unquote, but the online tutorial won't accept the answer. Using chicken scheme's interpreter:

```
#;3> (define nil '())
#;4>  (define thing (cons (cons (cons 1 nil) nil)
--->                         (cons (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))
--->                               (cons 2
--->                                    (cons 3 nil)))))
#;5> 
#;5> thing
(((1)) (2 3 4) 2 3)

#;25> `(,(car(cdr(car(cdr thing)))))
(3)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If any moderators see this, please close it.

Comment: No need to close, self-answered questions are acceptable :)

Comment: That looks like a great site, I'm trying to get started with sicp, I've just signed up. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I was just being silly. This works fine:

```
(cdr(cdr(cdr thing)))
```